# How to delete the path between two nodes, but not the nodes themselves in Inkscape?

Tags: inkscape, shapes, path, tools

I have a contour object, and I would like to delete a part of it (a line).

So I converted the object to a path, selected the *Edit paths by nodes* tool and deleted the unwanted nodes, now I have the contour but I'm still left with a bezier connecting the next two nodes.

I tried to delete that connection, but when I select it and delete it, Inkscape does not delete the line, but the nodes at both ends, which I didn't want.

How do I delete the line but keep the open contour? (So far it is a closed contour).

---

*Background: this object is a county, it is a map in general. I would like to keep all data inside the object except the lines which shows the borders of the county.*

Answer (score 49, accepted):

You need to use the "delete segment" button.

In the node tool, select the segment you want to remove. In the second line of the top toolbar, look for an icon that has two nodes connected with a line at the top, a down arrow, and two separate nodes at the bottom:

[image]

This will disconnect the nodes without deleting them. Here is the result:

[image]

Comment: Big "thanks" from your countryman :-)

Comment: I'm looking to do the same, but so that there's no fill or line between the two vectors at all. How can I do that?

Comment: The issue with this technique is that the gentle curve in the original is lost. Now there is just a straight edge between the two nodes. How can one delete the stroke (hide it) so that the edge can still be edited. This can be done in anime studio/mojo (so I know it is possible).

Comment: This is not possible. You need a separate shape for the stroke.

Comment: Sorry, extreme beginner here, but how do you select a segment between 2 nodes? Can't find it online, for some reason.